# Embedding slideshare presentation in django project - blank page on production

Tags: html, django, iframe

I'm trying to embed slideshare presentation in my django project. I use such tag:

```
<iframe 
    src="http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/XXXXXXXX" 
    width="342" 
    height="291" 
    frameborder="0" 
    marginwidth="0" 
    marginheight="0" 
    scrolling="no" 
    style="border:1px solid #CCC; border-width:1px 1px 0; margin-bottom:5px; max-width: 100%;" 
    allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

It works perfectly fine on my localhost, but on my django production server (on digital ocean) with my custom domain it just fails. It loads blank page. Do you know why that might happen?

Edit:

Important information - it fails on chrome and firefox. It works on chrome on iphone and safari on mac. Not tested on IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out it's actually pretty simple. Chrome and Firefox makes sure that the code is trusted. Since I use SSL, then the address should be

```
src="//www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/XXXXXXXX"
```

And it will adapt to http/https depending on server